# ng-repeat para duplicar <tds>

Tags: angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/q4wrkpkb/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola, estoy intentando construir una tabla, pero específicamente tengo un problema con una fila, en la que necesito que este pedazo:

```
<td ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-book' tile='Permiso de Lectura'>primero</i></td>
<td ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' tile='Permiso de Escritura'>segundo</i></td> 
<td ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' tile='Permiso de Eliminación'>tercero</i></td>
```

Necesito que esto sea generado dinámicamente, en mi caso con esto ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios" se generaria 2 veces justo lo que necesito.

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Tipo de Contenido</th>
    <th colspan="{{aTipoUsuarios.length * 3}}">
      Tipo de Usuarios
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios" colspan="3">
    {{usu}}
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>  

<!--Aqui necesito usar el ng-repeat ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios" 
para que se muestre esto en mi caso 2 veces-->

    <td ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-book' tile='Permiso de Lectura'>primero</i></td>
    <td ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' tile='Permiso de Escritura'>segundo</i></td>
    <td ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' tile='Permiso de Eliminación'>tercero</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="rol in aRoles">
   <td>{{rol.tipo_contenido}}</td>
   <td >1</td>
   <td >1</td>
   <td >1</td>
   <td >1</td>
   <td >1</td>
   <td >1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

He intendado todo pero no consigo, lograr duplicar ese pedazo por medio de un ng-repeat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa mi respuesta porfavor

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de 3 TDs con las palabras hard-coded, podés poner uno solo con la misma información pero generada dinámicamente.

Esta lista dinámica tendría una base de 3 elementos (primero, segundo y tercero, con la respectiva información de clases y títulos). Esta lista, la repetis tantas veces como elementos tenga aTipoUsuarios. Entonces, por ejemplo, si tenés 2 tipos de usuarios, te quedaría una lista con 6 elementos y, por consiguiente, 6 TDs.

Paso el ejemplo de código:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table border='1'>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3">Tipo de Contenido</th>
      <th colspan="{{aTipoUsuarios.length * 3}}">
        Tipo de Usuarios
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="usu in aTipoUsuarios" colspan="3">
        {{usu}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="columna in aColumnas"><i class='glyphicon {{columna.clasesCss}}' tile='{{columna.title}}'>{{columna.titulo}}</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="rol in aRoles">
        <td>{{rol.tipo_contenido}}</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.aRoles = [{
    "tipo_contenido": "articulos",
    "tipo_usuario": {
      "administrador": {
        "escritura": true,
        "lectura": true,
        "eliminacion": true
      },
      "reportante": {
        "escritura": true,
        "lectura": true,
        "eliminacion": true
      }
    }
  }, {
    "tipo_contenido": "informacion",
    "tipo_usuario": {
      "administrador": {
        "escritura": true,
        "lectura": true,
        "eliminacion": true
      },
      "reportante": {
        "escritura": true,
        "lectura": true,
        "eliminacion": true
      }
    }
  }, ]
  $scope.aTipoUsuarios = Object.keys($scope.aRoles[0].tipo_usuario);

  $scope.aColumnas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.aTipoUsuarios.length; i++) {
    $scope.aColumnas.push({
      titulo: "primero",
      clasesCss: "glyphicon-book",
      title: "Permiso de Lectura"
    });
    $scope.aColumnas.push({
      titulo: "segundo",
      clasesCss: "glyphicon-pencil",
      title: "Permiso de Escritura"
    });
    $scope.aColumnas.push({
      titulo: "tercero",
      clasesCss: "glyphicon-trash",
      title: "Permiso de Eliminación"
    });
  }

}
```

También actualicé el fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4wrkpkb/13/

Comment: necesito, acomodarlo tal cual a esa estructura, o quizas no te entienda

Comment: @yavg, Ahí actualicé la explicación. Avisame si es lo que estás necesitando.